# Add request (JWT Token) header when loading swagger.json with Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

**Shorter story:**

How can I convince Swagger UI to send `authorization` header when changing `Spec` (swagger end point) if user is authenticated in swagger-ui?

**Longer story:**

I added oauth2 to swagger.

```
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc($"1.0-{item.Name}", new Info
            {
                Title = $"1.0-{item.Title}",
                Version = $"1.0-{item.Version}"
            });
        }
        c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
                { "oauth2", new string[] { } }
        });
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
        {
            Type = "oauth2",
            Flow = "password",
            TokenUrl = this.Configuration["Domain"] + "api/authorization/token"
        });
        c.IncludeXmlComments(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"/Files/Web.xml");
    });
```

An `Authorize` button is shown and I can login with username, password.
When I call any API controller method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) `authorization` header is added to `Request headers`:

```
accept: text/plain
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,sl;q=0.7
authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR...
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

But when I change specification:
[image: screenshot]
a new request is made to server for `swagger.json` file (swagger end point).
Problem is this request doesn't have `auhorization` header. How can I add this header, when requesting swagger end-point?

I am trying to follow [official documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#modify-swagger-with-request-context) to filter result based on authenticated user. (Show empty result for unauthorised user.)
Something like that:

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
    {
        var isLoggedIn = httpReq.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    });
});
```

But Claims are empty, because `authorization` header is missing.

Comment: No such an option right now, the swagger.json files are meant to be open to all, and the auth is only applied to the actions, but the swagger-ui is OpenSource, you can propose that new feature to the UI team see what they have to say: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/new?template=Feature_request.md

Comment: Thank you. Now [everything is in author hands](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4883).

Comment: You are welcome, but don't leave it just up to the authors & committers ... if this is important to you, fork the repo and research a possible solution, stay active and let the team know your findings.